# Color the text of an item while using task

Tags: color, tasks

i am using task to make multiple columns, now I would like to color the text including the index.

I have been able to color the text but not the index as follows

```
 \begin{tasks}[counter-format =(tsk[1]), label-offset=1.25em](2)
      \task {\color{red} $f(x)=3x-2$ y $g(x)= x+6$.
      \task $f(x)=x^{2}$ y $g(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}$.
 \end{tasks}
```

How do I do that?

If I use `{\color{red}` before `\task` it will give me an error.
Keep in mind that I do not want to color every item.

Comment: Make a complete example. That will it make much easier for others to test solutions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to be missing the closing brace: `{\color{red} $f(x)=3x-2$ y $g(x)= x+6$.}`

Answer (score 3):

First things first: your code

```
\task {\color{red} $f(x)=3x-2$ y $g(x)= x+6$.
```

is missing a closing brace. But the opening brace isn't necessary in the first place if you want to color the whole item.

---

With older versions of `tasks` coloring the item label is not possible without modifying internals. But it is not very hard with an up to date version of `tasks`, v1.0 (2019/10/08) or greater:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
  label =(\arabic*),
  label-offset=1.25em ,
  label-width = 13pt ,
  item-indent = 25.6pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $f(x)=3x-2$ y $g(x)= x+6$.
  \task[\color{red}\refstepcounter{task}\thetask] \color{red}$f(x)=x^{2}$ y $g(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}$.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 01.02.20220**: add `\refstepcounter{task}` which is needed since v1.3a (2021/02/20)